# Paramiko SSH Powershell Script run as administrator

Tags: windows, paramiko

I have a Powershell Script that requires administrator rights to run.
Currently I have a Python script which SSH into this server and does a SFTP to copy the Powershell script into the server.
I also managed to run the Powershell script via my Python script using Paramiko. However, I am getting an error in my printed stdout as this Powershell script requires administrator rights to run.

I am wondering if it is possible to use Paramiko to escalate the rights so it would run as administrator.
I am logged onto the administrator account. It is just that the Powershell window itself isn't escalated, which can normally be done by right clicking and run as administrator. However, as this is SSH done via Paramiko, I am unsure how this could be done.

I've tried using runas, but as runas prompts back for a password, I am unable to enter the password as this is all done via a Python Script.

Below are my codes:

```
class MySFTPClient(paramiko.SFTPClient):
  def put_dir(self, source, target):
    ''' Uploads the contents of the source directory to the target path. The
        target directory needs to exists. All subdirectories in source are
        created under target.
    '''
    for item in os.listdir(source):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, item)):
            self.put(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))
        else:
            self.mkdir('%s/%s' % (target, item), ignore_existing=True)
            self.put_dir(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))

  def mkdir(self, path, mode=511, ignore_existing=False):
    ''' Augments mkdir by adding an option to not fail if the folder exists  '''
    try:
        super(MySFTPClient, self).mkdir(path, mode)
    except IOError:
        if ignore_existing:
            pass
        else:
            raise


transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = MySFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp.mkdir(target_path, ignore_existing=True)
sftp.put_dir(source_path, target_path)

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)

cmd = "powershell -InputFormat none -OutputFormat TEXT ./script.ps1"

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
print (stdout.readlines())

sftp.close()
```